# How to handle nested template variables?

Tags: python, django, html, django-templates

I currently have an embedded `<iframe>` that has a hard wired static url:

```
<iframe src="{% static 'docs/ver600/technical-reference-guide/_build/html/index.html' %}" frameborder="0" class="full-screen"></iframe>
```

I would like replace parts of the static string with variables.

For example, the "technical-reference-guide" is just a document name variable.  Obviously, just embedding a template variable doesn't work:

```
<iframe src="{% static 'docs/ver600/{{ doc_name }}/_build/html/index.html' %}" frameborder="0" class="full-screen"></iframe>
```

What would the best way for handling this type of dynamic interaction within a template?

Also, the document name is derived from the page slug:

```
{% page_attribute 'slug' %}
```

if that alters responses at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `add` filter ([docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add)). It can chain together strings and variable values (assuming they're also strings) inside a template tag.

Example:

```
{% static 'docs/ver600/'|add:doc_name|add:'/_build/html/index.html' %}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have been trying to get this to work but can't seem to.  I am setting the variable by `{% page_attribute 'slug' as doc_name %}` but the template reports a missing variable.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  The problem was that I was calloing `{% page_attribute 'slug' as doc_name %}` in an extend template, but I was doing so outside of a `{% block %}` area.  Moving it inside my main content block solved the issue.  Thanks!