# Accessing nested list by variable in Django templates

Tags: django

Assume that `nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

In this case, `{{ nested_list.0.1 }}` would print `2` in template

---

**Q. How can I access to nested list by variable in template ?**

For example, `{{ nested_list.{{ some_variable }}.1 }}`. Where `some variable` contains the index that I wish to retrieve (0 in the first example). Of course, it yields `TemplateSyntaxError`.

Comment: You are talking about nesting of template variables. This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391133/how-to-handle-nested-template-variables

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, that solution didn't solved my problem. I've tried `{{ nested_list.add:some_variable }}` which yields nothing.

Comment: hmm, maybe consider using dict? See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1724201/953553

Comment: you might want to implement a custom [`template filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: @ErnestTen Thanks. Your answer helped me a lot. So the conclusion is that it is impossible from template side. I'd preprocess using `zip` function in controller.

Comment: I've added an extra sentence to better explain what (I think) you are trying to do, please revert and explain if this is incorrect

Comment: Even though I use `template filter`, I should use variable in another variable. So it could not solve the problem.

Comment: Also, potentially off topic but it slightly looks as though you are trying to do logic in the template. It may be preferred to do this preprocessing in the view

Comment: @Sayse Yes, I agree with you. Thanks for your recommendation.